# Role based navigation to areas at registeration and login time ASP.NET CORE DefaultIdentity

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-roles

I am working on a project in which when user register himselft it is assgigned a role(At Registeration Time) like doctor or patient and depending on that role he will be redirected to Doctor or Patient Areas.
Same for login,when login user will be redirected to its specific areas.

Currently I am using this approach(Shown Below) but It throws an error.

```
If(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
 return RedirectToAction("ActionName","ControllerName",new {areas ="areas"});
}else
{
 return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Firstly when i login user with admin role it will not redirected to Area specified,it goes to else part...

Comment: 1. Are you using the built-in ASP.NET Core Identity or  a custom Form-Based Page? 2. Which version of ASP.NET Core are you using? 3. "but It throws an error.": Which error did you get? 4. Did you invoke `AddDefaultIdentity<User>(opt =>{...}).AddRoles<Role>()` to enable Role-related service?

Comment: 1) Yes, I am using build-in ASP.NET Core Identity.
2)I am using .Net Core 2.2

Comment: Did you try `AddRoles<Role>()` ?

Comment: 1) Yes, I am using build-in ASP.NET Core Identity.
2)I am using .Net Core 2.2
3)Its didn't throw error but it didnt go to the area specified
4)services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddDefaultUI();

Comment: Please try `services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser,IdentityRole>() .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()`